# Convert InputStream to File

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, inputstream, tesseract

I have a REST webservice built with [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) that does OCR (Optical Character Recognition) using Tesseract via the [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) Java binding. Now the Tess4J library expects you to send it an image file (png, jpg, tif amongst others), but with Jersey processing I get an InputStream that *contains* the image.

How do I convert this InputStream to a file type that Tesseract would recognise? I've tried the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

.....

private static File stream2file (InputStream in) throws IOException {            

    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("stream2file", ".tmp");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();

    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }

    return tempFile;            
}
```

But then the Tesseract library throws an exception saying that it doesn't accept the file type I'm sending (Which now in this case is 'tmp'). I've tried changing that little 'tmp' to 'tif' and other supported file types but that just yielded the same results, so I'm obviously missing something here.

So how can I take an InputStream, convert it, and forward it to Tesseract as one of the supported file types that it expects?

Comment: How do you get the InputStream from the WebService call? Have you ever tried to open the temp file using a different image processing tool like `Image Magick`? Does your Image file (tmp file) have the expected size? ... btw. Java 7 `java.nio.file.Files` supports copying `InputStreams` to paths.

Comment: I get the image via a form ('multipart/form-data') using POST. Nothing wrong with the image though, works perfectly in my console app that uses Tess4J. I haven't tried Image Magick no, I just might.

Comment: And the Temp File has the same size and content as the original file? Does tesseract invoked from the command prompt accept the temp file

Comment: By the way, `.deleteOnExit();` won't actually delete the temp file until the JVM shuts down successfully (and only if it is shuts down successfully). You should consider using a something like `try { ... } finally { tempFile.delete(); }`. Read more from Oracle on `deleteOnExit` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()).

Answer (score 2):

The file extension of the temp file has to match that of the original input image file.

Besides `File` type, [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-1.2/) also accepts `BufferedImage` as input. Just convert inputstream to it, as follows:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile))`. You have got an error at this line.
You should use `FileOutputStream (String)` not `FileOutputStream(File)`.
So it should be `FileOutputStream(tempfile.getName())`.

The parameter you pass to the constructor of `FileOutputStream` is a string that is the path to the real file or the name of the file. It's not a `File` object.